# Cmake can't find X11 libs

Tags: x11, libraries, cmake

I'm trying to compile a GUI-based package on my RHEL 7.2 (XFCE environment). But every time I run `cmake ..` , it fails with the report:

```
[user@localhost build]$ cmake ..
-- BUILD TYPE set to the default type:  'Release'
-- Setting fallback CUDA_ARCH=35
-- Setting cpu precision to double
-- Setting gpu precision to single
-- Using cuda wrapper to compile....
-- Cuda version is >= 7.5 and single-precision build, enable double usage warning.
-- MPI_INCLUDE_PATH : /usr/local/openmpi-3.0/include
-- MPI_LIBRARIES : /usr/local/openmpi-3.0/lib/libmpi.so
-- MPI_CXX_INCLUDE_PATH : /usr/local/openmpi-3.0/include
-- MPI_CXX_LIBRARIES : /usr/local/openmpi-3.0/lib/libmpi.so
-- 
-- ------------------ YOU HAVE NO X11-LIBS ------------------
-- CCmake found no X11-libs on your system, which are required for the GUI.
--  You CAN add the flag -DGUI=OFF to avoid using X11
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:200 (message):
  X11 is required for GUI.
```

I also checked for the installed X11 libraries in my system:

```
[root@localhost build]# rpm -qa | grep libX11
libX11-devel-1.6.5-1.el7.x86_64
libX11-common-1.6.5-1.el7.noarch
libX11-1.6.5-1.el7.x86_64
```

Despite this other GUI programs are running fine. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: X11 files are a lot more than `libX11-devel`. And some build scripts will reply for any missing parts of X11 without being specific. Please do `# yum install libXmu-devel`, which will install "the usual required X11 collection".

Comment: @Kund I have `libXmu-devel libSM-devel libICE-devel` installed in my system, still cant proceed with `cmake`.

Comment: Is cmake still asking for X11-libs ?

Comment: Yes. Still giving the same error. @Kund

Comment: I'm not building an XFCE package. I'm building an open source package on XFCE env

Comment: Relion-2.3 is the package @Knud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS 7 example, building Relion.

```
# yum install openmpi-devel fftw-devel fltk-devel
# cp /usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/* /usr/bin/

git clone https://github.com/3dem/relion.git
cd relion/
mkdir -p external/fltk/lib      // 'make install' fails if no (empty) lib/ folder
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake ..
make
.
[100%] Built target tiltpair_plot

# make install
```

Result : `Relion-git.040918-1.el7.x86_64.rpm` ( 2.0MB ) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c3loJFCladmqvemHyKu44FxZzdOr-XJN/view?usp=sharing → Provides /usr/local/bin/{45 files}, /usr/local/lib/{ gui_background.xpm, **librelion_gui_lib.so, librelion_lib.so** }

Download, and install : `cd Downloads/ && yum install ./Relion-git.040918-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`

`$ relion` : The Relion GUI opens OK.

---

```
$ ldd relion | grep Xlib
        libXrender.so.1 => /lib64/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f2cf841c000)
        libXcursor.so.1 => /lib64/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f2cf8211000)
        libXfixes.so.3 => /lib64/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f2cf800b000)
        libXext.so.6 => /lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f2cf7df8000)
        libXft.so.2 => /lib64/libXft.so.2 (0x00007f2cf7be2000)
        libXinerama.so.1 => /lib64/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f2cf77a1000)
        libX11.so.6 => /lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f2cf7463000)
        libXau.so.6 => /lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f2cf60b7000)
```

`# yum provides */libXcursor.so.1`,
Etc. etc. to decide the names of your "missing libX**-devel".

Comment: I performed the exact same steps, yet I'm stuck with the same error !

Comment: Solution : Get the rpm package, and install it with `yum`. ( No CUDA )

Comment: Alright but without CUDA its highly time-inefficient to use the package.

Comment: @Kund I have all the Xlib (you mentioned) present in `/usr/lib64`, however can't resolve the issue. I don't get it why `cmake` cant find these !! 
Is there any way to manually point the libraries to `cmake` ?

Comment: Did you install all `libX[name]-devel` ? ... I.e. "so.1" won't do for cmake. Files required for compiling are **libX[name].so** , found in packages-devel. .... And by the way, no reason to build anything when you can install `Relion-git.040918-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: @Kund I had installed the `rpm` but after successful installation when I ran `relion` it gave me an error: `relion: error while loading shared libraries: librelion_lib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. That is why I'm trying to build it.

Comment: ? May be you lost /usr/local/bin/ from the LD_LIBRARY_PATH ? → See edited answer.

Comment: Building on my previous attempt for building from Source > Including X11 header files manually to the ''/usr/include'' moved the installation quite a bit but again stuck at:
`/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:1686:1: error: ‘_X_DEPRECATED’ does not name a type
 _X_DEPRECATED
 ^
/usr/include/X11/Xlib.h:3571:3: error: expected initializer before ‘_X_SENTINEL’
 ) _X_SENTINEL(0);`

Comment: Thank you. 
Both worked for me. `.rpm` also worked and simultaneously I have been able to build from the source. Thanks a lot !